# SVGO - Add Plugin

Tags: node.js, svg, plugins, svgo

This might be a silly question...

I've installed SVGO from https://github.com/svg/svgo

I want to turn on the plug-ing that does this:

> apply transforms, crop by real width, center vertical alignment and
>   resize SVG with one Path inside (disabled by default)

How do I do this?

From what I understand, I need to find a config file and add it to a plug in list. I'm not sure where to begin. Please help :D

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [`transformsWithOnePath`](https://github.com/svg/svgo/blob/master/plugins/transformsWithOnePath.js) plugin. To use plugons disabled by default you just have to provide a `config` Object when instantiate `SVGO`.

For example:

```
var SVGO = require('svgo'),
    svgo = new SVGO({ 
      plugins: [{
        transformsWithOnePath: {
          width: 200,
          height: 100,
          scale: 10
      }
  }]
});
```

Seems that this specific plugin applies a serie of transformations on `SVG` files with only one path inside.

In case you want to add more plugins, just append it to the `plugin` Array on the configuration object.